# how to align background image but without repeats or white borders

Tags: css, background, background-image

Problem is that my client wants himself as a background for his website, when I designed it his face was placed perfectly beside the logo. Unfortunately when the website was already built,his face was covered by the logo.
So I made my container to have the same width as the design had but my client doesn't support having white spaces or repeats, he also doesn't want to have the logo moved either.

what I am asking  can I increase the size of my background image and move it around just the way I would have in Photoshop or some website builder?

Thank you

Comment: Use background-position https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use background properties like

```
.bgimg{
    background-image: url('mybg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat; // this will stop repeating your img
    background-position: center center; // your bg img position could be in % too like 50% 50%;
}
```